# Need to customize xlabs calendar day cell in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I am using XLabs CalendarView to look my calendar as attached image but i am facing issues to customizedaycell to get expected output

xlab calender control link https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Calendar-Control

[image]

I need the number below date on some date cells.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I got source code for XLabs Calendar and I changed few lines of code to show hours to the below side of the day in the calendar (which is shown in the attached image above in green and red colour ) but that is hard coded string which I have passed I want to pass dynamic value for every day cell view,  may be with in few hours I will share the code,  stay tune and please help...

Comment: @Sanket I need same concept in calendar, please let me know solution if you have. I will appreciate.